# Wrong width calculation for words in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have a [PDF](http://www.filedropper.com/answers1), which has `WinAnsiEncoding(Times)` and it do not have any `toUnicode` or differences encoding. 
When I try to select or highlight text, width of text is not calculated properly.

I have all the widths but somehow width is calculated incorrectly. 
What can be the problem?
 How can I get correct CID of character in order to find correct width of the glyph? 
 I have attached screenshots for the same. "**EXPLANATIONS**" word is not selected completely. This can happen only if the widths of glyph are calculated incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: Acrobat selects it correctly. Don't forget that there are text operators that can stretch the text or alter the inter char spacing, there's more to take into account than just the plain char widtth.

Comment: Why do you think the character widths are calculated wrong? That text clearly has custom spacing; checking the PDF confirms this: `0.667 Tc  % set character spacing to 0.6670`. Are you not simply forgetting to take that into account? (We can't tell because you did not provide the code you are using.)

Comment: .. and a bit of horizontal scaling as well: `107.624 Tz`.

Comment: I have added character spacing as well..
I am using PDFKitten code and it does not make any use of horizontal scaling. I have to correct it. Thanks for the quick response.. :)

Comment: Can you add that code to your question, please?

Comment: Fixed the problem by applying the horizontal scale on the width of the glyph.. Thanks for the help.. :)